# StratifiedKfolds with imbalanced data for multiclass classification

Tags: python, cross-validation, multiclass-classification, imbalanced-data

I'm trying to build a model of multiclass classification using imbalanced data with few samples(436) and 3 classes. After standardizing data I split it using `stratifiedkfolds` to be sure that my minority class is represented well on the train and test split:

```
sss = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, random_state=None, shuffle=False)#5/10/15/20
for train_index, test_index in sss.split(X, y):
    #print("Train:", train_index, "Test:", test_index)
    original_Xtrain, original_Xtest = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
    original_ytrain, original_ytest = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
```

I've read that feature selection and oversampling should be applied only to the training set, and that's exactly what I did.

```
#I did feature selection before this
smote = SMOTE('not majority')
X_sm, y_sm = smote.fit_resample(original_Xtrain, original_ytrain)
print(X_sm.shape, y_sm.shape)
```

Then I trained my model using the training set oversampled by SMOTE, at this point I want to use `cross-validation` but I don't know should I use the stratified parameter used before or I can set my new cv to a new value like 5 splits or either use `ShuffleSplit`

```
for key, classifier in classifiers.items():
    classifier.fit(X_sm, y_sm)
    training_score1 = cross_val_score(classifier, X_sm, y_sm,scoring=make_scorer(f1_score, average='macro'),error_score="raise", cv=5)
    print("Classifiers: ", classifier.__class__.__name__, "Has a training score of", round(training_score1.mean(), 2) * 100, "% F1  score")
    training_score2 = cross_val_score(classifier, X_sm, y_sm,scoring=make_scorer(roc_auc_score, average='macro',multi_class='ovo', needs_proba=True),error_score="raise", cv=5)
    print("Classifiers: ", classifier.__class__.__name__, "Has a training score of", round(training_score2.mean(), 2) * 100, "% Roc_auc score")
```

Well, I tried them both but using a new cv parameter gives me the best results. I think in the case of imbalanced data `stratifiedkfolds` replace the `test_train_split` and no need to use it again on the `cross validation` but I'm not sure about this. Can you please tell me if I missed something in my process? am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Are you using the oversampled data for the cross validation?

Comment: yes that's exactly what i did

Comment: I don't recomend doing it, as you said "oversampling should be applied only to the training set" when you do cross validation there is a test set that was oversampled. To fix this you can use some KFold class and oversample the data once is splited.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get it. I oversampled only the train split of stratifiedkfolds, not the test so I use only the train oversampled. I edited the post can you check it again please?

Comment: My bad, the indentation got me. Are you making the cross_validation inside the KFold for loop? If that is the case, why? You are alredy doing cross validation, just use the `original_Xtest` data and you will end up with 5 scores one per split.

Answer (score 0):

This is your cross_validation strategy:

```py
sss = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, random_state=None, shuffle=False)#5/10/15/20
```

You don't need another one inside the loop.

---

> using a new cv parameter gives me the best results.

It does because you are using oversampled data as test data inside this:

```py
training_score1 = cross_val_score(classifier, X_sm, y_sm,scoring=make_scorer(f1_score, average='macro'),error_score="raise", cv=5)
```

But you already know you shouldn't do it

> oversampling should be applied only to the training set

Let me know if I miss something.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking, I was sure that I'm doing something wrong but what confused me is the use of stratifiedKfolds to split the data instead of using train_test_split. In other machine learning models we split the data with train_test_split then we set a new kfold so we split it again for cross-validation, and as stratifiedkfolds replace the train_test_split in the case of imbalanced data classification I thought I should split it again for cross-validation as we usually do. I'm still confused as it's my first try on imbalanced data.